# How can I copy to clipboard an specific item in an array and how can i detect which one is clicked? in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have an array of objects showing them in a table and one of the objects in this array is something that I want to copy to clipboard which has a copy icon button next to it but when i set the copy function it copies all the other objects in the array and I do not know how to detect which index has been clicked for copy!

```
const data = [
{title: "first", number: 1234},
{title: "second", number: 5678},
]

const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

const handleCopy = () => {
    setCopied(data.map((item) => item.number));
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(data.map((item) => item.number));
    toast({
      position: "top",
      isclosable: true,
      duration: 1500,
      render: () => <BaseAlert title="number copied!" />,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      setCopied("");
    }, 3000);
  };

<button onClick={handleCopy}>Copy</button>
```

When I click on the Copy button it copies two numbers in the array
output: 1234, 5678
while i want to detect which button has been clicked to copy 1234 OR 5678!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send the array index to the `handleCopy`  function, then get that number from `data` array like this:

```
const handleCopy = (index) => {
    setCopied(data[index].number);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(data[index].number);
    // ...rest
  };
```